# Weird characters rendering on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-8.5

I need some help. I have an old website hosted on IIS 8.5 on a Windows Server 2012 R2 and today its not working anymore. The event viewer doesnt show any erros but if I inspect the code on Chrome or IE it renders like this:

[image]

And also sometimes it shows strange characters:

[image]

Does anyone knows whats happening and how to fix it? There is no new code or changes to the project.

Comment: Inspect the code in Notepad or another text editor rather than Chrome or IE. Try Notepad++, and use View->Show Symbol->Show All Characters from the menu. There's not a thing we can do with two images and no source.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, try to restart IIS and see if that helps.

I've run into it a couple of times, often when multiple sites are hosted in the IIS. I don't know if it's the handlers or filters that eventually gets bogged down and starts to act wierd, and I've honestly not bothered to troubleshoot it further than restarting IIS, or in worst case, the server.